# Is there a recommended size of count when scan keys in redis?

Tags: python, redis

I would like to find keys matching a pattern with `scan`, and is there a recommended value for its parameter count?

```
def keys(r, pattern):

    original_cur = 0
    cur, first_scan_keys = r.scan(original_cur, match=pattern, count=10000)

    res = first_scan_keys
    while cur != 0:
        cur, new_keys = r.scan(cur, match=pattern, count=10000)
        if new_keys:
            res.extend(new_keys)

    print res
```

When a small value such as 100 is used, the `RTT` is too expensive, however, when a huge value is used, `scan` becomes something like `keys` which will block redis.

I just wonder is there a method to calculate a value of count to balance `RTT` and the block time? May be 1% of all the keys?

Comment: There are no free lunches... and I think you meant RTT instead of ttl.